# Counterexample to isomorphisms between tensor product of finite-dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

One of my homework problems required me to prove that

> If $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces, then prove that
> \begin{equation*}
> V^{\ast} \otimes W^{\ast} \cong \mathcal{L}(V, W; \mathbb{R}) \cong \mathcal{L}(V \otimes W; \mathbb{R})
> \end{equation*}
> and
> \begin{equation*}
> V^{\ast} \otimes W \cong \mathcal{L}(V; W),
> \end{equation*}

where $\mathcal{L}(V_1, \ldots, V_n; W)$ means all multilinear maps $f \colon V_{1} \times \ldots \times V_{n} \rightarrow W$. I was able to prove the above and it required a dimension argument, i. e. used the fact that the vector spaces are finite-dimensional.

> But then I was trying to come up with an infinite-dimensional example such that the above isomorphisms would fail but I can't seem to find one. I would assume that an example where the dimension of the dual space is larger should do the trick. **Is there an obvious straight forward counterexample to the above isomorphisms that I am simply missing?**

Comment: There are two different things: (i) showing that the natural map that is an isomorphism in the finite-dimensional case  is not an isomorphism in the general case, and (ii) showing that there is no isomorphism.

Comment: It's certainly possible to choose a $W$ (of infinite dimension) such that $\dim(V^* \otimes W) < \dim(V^* \otimes W^*) = \dim\mathcal L(V,W)^*$. However, I'm not sure if this ensures that $\dim\mathcal L(V,W) > \dim(V^* \otimes W)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mariano's comment explains, there are two things that one could consider here: one is that the natural (injective) map from $V^* \otimes W$ to $\mathcal L(V,W)$ might fail to be an isomorphism, and the second is that $V^* \otimes W$ might fail to be isomorphic to $\mathcal L(V,W)$.

For the first of these situations, a (relatively) simple counterexample is as follows. Take $V = W = c_{00}(\Bbb R)$, the set of sequences of real numbers for which only finitely many numbers in the sequence are non-zero.

Let $\Phi:V^* \otimes W \to \mathcal L(V,W)$ denote the map $\Phi(f \otimes w)(v) = f(v) w$. Note that for all linear maps $\alpha$ in the image of $\Phi$, there exists an $N \in \Bbb N$ sufficiently large so that for all $i > N$ and all $v \in V$, $[\alpha(v)]_i = 0$. However, there exist elements of $\mathcal L(V,W)$ (such as the identity map) that do not have this property.